# How were the first computers on the internet connected?

Tags: technology, internet

The internet started as a small "net" of interconnected computers, but how were those computers connected? Was a chip manufactured to be installed onto the computer? Was it software?

Comment: Your titled asked about "**wirelessly** connected computers" but the body appears to be asking about the **internet** instead. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Semaphore Yes, sorry - I've edited the question.

Comment: Thanks. The main problem (as I see it) is, *which event* do you consider to be the first time computers were connected to the Internet?

Comment: @Semaphore When the first Wide Area Network was established

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the question - obviously there has to be a hardware component. Or is your question whether the connection ran on telegraph masts or could already use the telephone network?

Comment: According to wiki, in the late 50's the SAGE was connected via hardened AT&T phone lines.

Comment: There were no chips at the time

Comment: I was hesitant to downvote, in order not to discourage tech-history questions such as this one… but it's really written too poorly, so much that I'm not sure what he's asking either. A rewrite would likely help much.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes. The question is fine. The answer is also fine and has been accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia article on ARPANET explains the earliest architecture. Communication was over leased telephone lines using acoustic modems. Each node was run by a small, specialized computer that did routing. Communication between the routers and the local computers was through a serial port. To read the packets off the serial port, the local machine would have to have some kind of software installed (what we would call today a "tcp/ip stack").

Comment: well, those 'small' computers were still huge by today's standards. Think PDPs :)